# PostgreSQL on AWS EC2 Spot

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is it possible to setup fail-safe Postgresql on EC2 spot?

I have only one variant for now - setup 3 EC2 instances:

- any small EC2 as non spot for loadbalancer (haproxy?)
- any small EC2 SPOT as slave PostgreSQL
- necessary "big" EC2 SPOT as Master PostgreSQL

So, I think, you already understand the schema - haproxy will send traffic for working VM, mostly on Master PSQL VM, and, during Master VM reboot (it will take some minutes maximum), traffic will go to slave VM for these minutes.

So, both postgresql will be setup as cluster master-slave.

My question is - is it working schema? Is there some other easier ways to implement it?

My goal - have "big powerful" and cheap instance (SPOT) for Postgresql (v11), but in same time I want keep it stable =)

Comment: You do not want to put your production database on a Spot instance. It can be turned off at any time. How would traffic be redirected to the "secondary" server if the "primary" database is turned off? What mechanism would trigger this shift? Then, if new data is written to the secondary database, how does it get back to the primary database? Is your application not worth spending money to keep it up and running?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Spot instance is not a good choice for a workload that requires running for a longer period without interrupting. At any minute your spot instance can go away with two minutes notification.

So if you evaluate to set up a database on EC2 you must pick on-demand or reserved types of payment options.

However, if you do not want to manage your own database, please do consider an RDS instead of your own setup